# shell scripting - print files in adirectory

Tags: scripting

I am writing simple Script which displays regular files in a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in "$@"
do
if [ -f "$FILE" ]
then
ls -l "$FILE"
fi
done
```

Even though my directory have 2 files, this script is not showing anything.
Can some one please what is wrong in my script?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you go for simple command like :

```
ls -p|grep -v /
```

coming to your issue :

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in "$@"
do
if [ -f "$FILE" ]
then
ls -l "$FILE"
fi
done
```

try this

```
for FILE in $@/*
```

instead of

```
for FILE in "$@"
```